# Converting a hexadecimal character to an int in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pyglet

I'm using the graphics library [Pyglet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyglet) to do some drawing and want to get the resulting image out as a Python list (so I can convert it to a [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array).

Pyglet gives me a string of hex characters, like this: '\xff' (indicating a value of 255 at one pixel). How can I convert such a string to an int?

I've tried int('\xff', 16), but that doesn't work. Note that according to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), '\xnn' is escaped and encoded as a hexedecimal char, but it doesn't tell me how to convert that to an int.

Comment: I think your real question should be: what is the best way to get an image into a numpy array. Have you tried `imread` function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get a NumPy array straight from a Python string, you can use

```
s = "\xff\x03"
a = numpy.frombuffer(s, numpy.uint8)
```

To get a list you can use

```
a =  map(ord, s)
```

An alternative to a list in Python 2.6 or above is to use `bytesarray(s)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
a = '\xff'
print int(a.encode('hex'), 16)
255
```

Edit: sorry, the previous version had a mistake - decode instead of encode. This works.

Edit 2: I actually misread the question, as commenters noted. This may be already obvious but in case someone finds it helpful the regular python list solution would be:

```
>>> a = '\xff\xfe'
>>> [str(ord(char)) for char in a]
['255', '254']
>>> ' '.join([str(ord(char)) for char in a])
'255 254'
```

Comment: But this only works for a single byte, and for a single byte it is equivalent to `ord(a)`, so it seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @Sven It seems to work fine for longer strings ``int("\xff\x34\xbf\x25".encode('hex'),16)`` -> 4281646885L

Comment: @ThomasH: This result is completely meaningless in the given context.  To convert the string to a list of integers, each byte of the string has to be treated separately.  Converting the whole string to a single integer certainly can be done this way, but this is completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Sven You are right. I just found your "But this only works for a single byte" formulation misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalised approach that handles a hex string with variable length substrings, e.g.:

```
s = '5b1\n5\n3ad44'
```

The following code transforms a string with 3 million variable length hex substrings to a numpy integer array in 2 seconds (on a MacBook) through vectorisation:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, cStringIO

s = ('5b1\n5\n3ad44\n' * 1000000)[:-1]    # 3m item hex string (variable element length)

# change hex to 2 digit decimal
for i in range(0,9): s = s.replace(str(i),'0' + str(i))  
for i in [['a','10'],['b','11'],['c','12'],['d','13'],['e','14'],['f','15']]:
    s = s.replace(i[0],i[1])

# read string into numpy
n = np.array(pd.read_csv(cStringIO.StringIO(s), header=None)[[0]]).astype('int64')    

# fix base
n = (n % 100) + 16 * ((n % 10000)/100) + 256 * ((n % 1000000)/10000) + 4096 * ((n % 100000000)/1000000) + 65536 * ((n % 10000000000)/100000000)

n[0:3]    # confirm correct transformation to [1457, 5, 240964]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `\xff` is the print representation of a hex value in a byte. But `int()` doesn't work on hex representations of bytes, but on string representation of numbers. A number in the base-16 world is '13' or 'ab' or 'ff'. Consequently (but still funnily), `int('ff',16)` works fine. If you want to go that route, you need to get rid of the '\x' :-).

Comment: Note that `"\xff"` is a string with a single character.  Your answer suggests this string has four characters.

Comment: @Sven You are right, but I just meant the last sentence metaphorically. Technically, the ``.encode`` approach from another answer would be the way to achieve that.